# CloudFormation - set multiple default values for type of List<>

Tags: list, aws-cloudformation, default

When I'm creating CloudFormation template with the use of interactive `Parameters`, I can define the type of List<> to be able to select multiple values, for example:

```
SubnetIds:
  Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  Description: Select multiple subnets from selected VPC.
  Default: "????"
```

or:

```
SecurityGroups:
  Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
  Description: Select security groups.
  Default: "???"
```

The question is how do I pre-set `default` value with multiple selections? if `default` takes only the string instead of a list, and string with commas between multiple values also doesn't help

Any ideas? please, hint me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recently run in the same issue.
The answer is simple - there should be no spaces in your comma-separated list.
So it would look like:

```
SecurityGroups:
  Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
  Description: Select security groups.
  Default: "sg-11111111,sg-22222222"
```

And this way the values would be preselected in your template.

P.S. Do not try CommaDelimitedList or so - it won't work in the way you want. The string values would be selected, but not the actual security groups.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165144

Comment: weird, I'm pretty sure I tried this, as I mentioned in my original question:
`and string with commas between multiple values also doesn't help`

and it didn't work! Are you sure it is working for you? hmm maybe I had coma and space between, ill double check! but thank you for a reply

Comment: @Briksins, yes, it did help. As far as I remember when it had a space between the values it just stated the same error or selected only first value.